# Client (Ubuntu 20.04) unable to access internet, but router is (Debian 10.5)

Tags: networking, internet, iptables, debian

I am completely new to this and was setting up a router and client for a practice lab.
The client is able to ping the router and the router is able to ping the client.
The router has access to the internet, but the client does not.
I cannot figure out why that is, will someone please help ?

Here is all the settings I have.

**Client  /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml**

```
network:
    version: 3
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
      enp0s3:
        dhcp4: no
        addresses:
          - 10.0.20.21/24
        gateway4: 10.0.20.1
        nameservers:
          addresses: [10.0.20.15, 8.8.8.8]
```

**Router: /etc/network/interfaces**

```
source /etc/nework/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#NAT Network
allow-hotplug enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 10.0.2.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.2.2
dns-nameserver 10.0.0.1
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

#Internal Network
allow-hotplug enp0s8
iface enp0se8 static 
address 10.0.20.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.20.15
network 10.0.20.0
broadcast 10.0.20.255
```

**Iptables rules**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp0s3 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s3 -o enp0s8 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i enp0s8 -o enp0s3 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Please post the output of "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" from the router.

Are you also trying to route through the router?  If so, the gateway on the client should be your router's IP.

Comment: Those DNS servers look wrong unless you have a local resolver.  If you're going to specify a local IP address for a client, then it needs a DHCP reservation.

Comment: @BrianTurek The output for that command on the router is '0'

Comment: @Nmath How can I check this ?

Comment: Are you trying to route through your router?

Comment: @BrianTurek Yes I am .

Comment: DNS nameserver: `8.8.8.8` is Google's Public DNS server (it's counterpart is `8.8.4.4`), but you also have nameservers set as  `10.0.20.15` and `10.0.0.1` - if those are not local devices capable of DNS lookup or forward then an invalid DNS server could prevent you from accessing the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problem areas:

- If you intend on your client to route through your router, the client's gateway must be set to the router's IP address

  - In your case, that means the client's gateway should be 10.0.20.15, not 10.0.20.1
- Your router needs to have IP forwarding enabled, there are a few ways of doing this:

  - Run (as root) `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`  Note that this will NOT persist across reboots
  - Run (as root) `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` Note that this will NOT persist across reboots
  - If you want for it to persist across reboots, edit /etc/sysctl.conf and ensure that the "net.ipv4.ip_forward" value is uncommented and set to "1".  This will not affect the current state of the OS so you'll need to do one of the above commands the first time.
- Remove the "gateway" entry from the router's enp0s8 config.  I don't know if it hurts but it doesn't make sense for the router to be its own gateway
- As someone else pointed out, it appears you have the client's DNS server set to be the router but (probably) don't have a DNS server running on the router. Remove the "10.0.20.15" entry from the client's nameserver list.
- As a FYI, it doesn't hurt but the "-A FORWARD" lines in your iptables rules are unnecessary assuming your default policy is "ACCEPT".

Assuming your router can access the internet, this should get you working.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much !